# Present a FormSheet QLPreVIewController within a UIVIewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to open QLPreVIewController as a from sheet model style.

Here is my code

```
    -(void)openPdfFile{

    QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

    [previewer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [previewer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];


    // Set data source
    [previewer setDataSource:self];
    [previewer setDelegate:self];
    // Which item to preview
    [previewer setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:TRUE];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]rootViewController]presentModalViewController:previewer animated:TRUE];

}
```

but it always present with full screen

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can push it into view using a UINavigationController object, or can present it modally, full screen

So, you could try presenting a navigation controller as a form sheet and pushing the preview controller as the root view controller.

Comment: it works for me.but now problem is that i have added left bar button in navigation controller. but it doesnt display

Comment: The bar buttons are specified by the preview controller. What did you try to do (you may want to start a new question).

Comment: Here is my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612906/qlpreviewviewcontroller-cant-set-left-bar-button-in-less-than-6-0-version