# QLPreviewVIewController can't set left bar button in less than 6.0 version?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an issue in set left bar button of my QLPreviewController.

Here is my code

```
    -(void)openPdfFile{


    QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

    previewer.dataSource=self;
    previewer.delegate=self;

    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:previewer];

    navController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(goback)];

    [navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]rootViewController]presentModalViewController:navController animated:TRUE];

}
```

it works fine in ios 6.0 and above but getting problem below 6.0. it doesn't display

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957091/qlpreviewcontroller-remove-or-add-uibarbuttonitems